# Issue with association creates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, associations

Here are my associations...

```
Account has_many :credits
Credit belongs_to :account
```

And I'm trying to run: `account.credits.current`

So, in that case, I've already got an `Account` object, and then I want to access a `current` method within the `Credit` model.

Here is that method...

```
def self.current
   # Find current credit line
   current = self.where(:for_date => Time.now.strftime("%Y-%m-01")).first

   # If we couldn't find a credit line for this month, create one
   current = Credit.create(:account_id => self.account.id, :for_date => Time.now.strftime("%Y-%m-01")) if current.blank?

   # Return the object
   current
end
```

The problem is on that second line...the one that should create a new credit entry if it can't find one. Specifically, I can't set what account it should be associated with. I just get an `undefined method 'account'` error.

Comment: Might be a long-shot, but have you tried just 'account.id' without self?

Comment: @Zenph: Yeah...and I get `undefined local variable or method 'account'` on that one.

Comment: Disclaimer: these self vs average definitions trip me up and I'm still learning, but what about if you move the method current out of self? Works fine locally: "def current account.id end" Credit.current returns associated account's id.

Comment: I've deleted my answer because I believe it is as simple as not specifying the account_id and creating through association. The association is maintained automatically as you are accessing it via account.credits. Use self.create instead of Credit.create and don't specify account_id.

Comment: @Shpigford You're trying to acccess instance properties through a class method. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create through association instead, and leave out the `account_id` as it will be linked automatically:

```
current = self.create(:for_date => Time.now.strftime("%Y-%m-01")) if current.blank?
```

Note: `self.create` instead of `Credit.create`.

Comment: Doesn't work. I can't access the `current` method without `self.` If i do, then I get `undefined method 'current'`.

Comment: I think the problem is the association, though. Have you tried `Account.find(1).credits.current`?

Comment: Sorry, I'll update my answer shortly. I didn't fully comprehend how you were trying to use this model.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted! I agree with the other answer too about the method 'current_or_create' as it is more explicit. You know exactly what the method is doing without browsing the internals.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access instance properties in a class method, that's not possible.

If you have this:

```
class Credit
   def self.current
      self.account
   end
end
```

It's the same as: `Credit.account`, which as I'm sure you understand, would not work.

Now, your method `current` has to be a class method if you want it to load on the plural association: ie:

With `def self.current` you can call `account.credits.current`

With `def current` you can call `account.credits[0].current` or `account.credits.where(...).current`

I hope this makes sense. Now, as for what to do about it...

My recommendation would be to make `current` a scope, like so:

```
class Credit
  scope :current, lambda { where(:for_date => Time.now.strftime("%Y-%m-01")).first }
  ...
end
```

Then you can use this scope anywhere and have an instance (or nil) at the end of it.

```
account.credits.create(...) unless accounts.credit.current
```

If you want to make a convenience method, I would then do:

class Credit
     def self.current_or_new
       self.current || self.create( :for_date => Time.now.strftime("%Y-%m-01") )
     end
   end

This should work the way you are intending. If it's called through an association, ie:

```
account.credits.current_or_new
```

Then the account_id will be put in for you by rails through the association.

Comment: The answer is above ^^ create through association.